# read and dispaly word by word from pdf using c#, automatically with time gap of 1 second in page

Tags: c#

Am having a pdf file. I need to read the content and display word by word from pdf, at a time gap of 1 second in page.

Here am able to read the pdf content, i need to display word by word (single word at a time gap of second) (word per second) in one textbox or label. I need help at this point.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried something? If so, how did it work out?

Comment: Yes which part do you want help on? Getting contents out of PDF or displaying words at 1 second intervals?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which part you're stuck on, but I'm assuming you mean showing the word a second at a time. I also assumed you meant a Windows Forms app - web app would need to be done with Javascript instead (`window.setInterval` will replace the timer).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    StringBuilder textDisplayed = new StringBuilder();
    int currentWord = 0;
    string[] words;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Dummy content, this comes from your PDF-reading code
        string textContent = "This is my test string that is appearing a word at a time, in one second intervals.";

        // Split the content into words
        words = textContent.Split(' ');

        // Create a timer that ticks every second
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        // Check whether we've passed the end of the document
        if (words.Length <= currentWord)
        {
            ((Timer)sender).Stop();
            return;
        }

        // Append the current word to the stringbuilder
        textDisplayed.Append(words[currentWord++]);
        textDisplayed.Append(" ");

        // Set the textbox content
        txtText.Text = textDisplayed.ToString();
    }
}
```